# How to re-run javascript core code for content loaded with jQuery's ajax()?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I'm trying to AJAXify page loads using `.load()`/`.get()` methods and the main problem I'm currently stuck with is that the loaded content isn't being processed by the relevant javascript code.

I've tried upgrading to jQuery 1.7 and addind this scary workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442723/how-to-convert-bind-pass-through-to-on-to-delegate-like-right-inside-jqu , but the problem is not in the `bind()` calls AFAIU.

Something with `Drupal.behaviors`?

The simplest way to reproduce the issue is to take a page's `#content`.innerHTML that is normally being processed by JS (`/admin/structure/block`) and replace the `#content` HTML with it. This way the resulting HTML is the same but [for me] it's not processed by JS functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Drupal.attachBehaviors(jQuery("#content")[0]);` is working. Some issues still exist though. Like the absence of relevant `behaviors` when loading from different page.

Taken from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3193/7177